# Jquery,AJAX not posting data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am facing problem while sendingsome  arrays and data to a page but it is not getting posted i tried print_r($_POST); but its showing Array() as output and other data is also not being posted

The script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(document).on('click', "#submitr", function(){

```
           var favorite = [];
           var tag = [];
           var type = [];
           var scheme = [];

           $.each($("input[name='pcheck']:checked"), function(){
               favorite.push($(this).val());
           });

           $.each($("input[name='tag[]']"), function(){
               tag.push($(this).val());
           });

           $.each($("input[name='type[]']"), function(){
               type.push($(this).val());
           });

           $.each($("input[name='scheme[]']"), function(){
               scheme.push($(this).val());
           });
           var count=$("#count").val();
           $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'reportr.php',
           data: {
           count:count,
           pcheck:favorite,
           tag : tag ,
           type : type,
           scheme : scheme

           },
           success: function() {
    window.location.href = "reportr.php";     }
           });

       });



</script>
```

On alert the values are being displayed

Comment: is this supposed to be `reportr.php` or `report.php`?

Comment: Please post the php code you're using to read the post data.

Comment: @lix it's reportr.php

Comment: Are you sure about that? Note that you are making 2 requests to `reportr.php`, first a POST request and when that is successful, a GET request; the redirect. You only show the results of the second requests and `$_POST` will be empty there.

Comment: what's your jquery version ?

Comment: As @jeroen pointed out you redirect the window to the php script on a succesful post. If you change your success function to this, what do you see in the developer console? `success: function(data) { console.log(data); }`

Comment: @jeroen thanks buddy it worked ...thank you ,i was not aware about those requests just wanted to send post data and load that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about that? Note that you are making 2 requests to `reportr.php`, first a POST request and when that is successful, a GET request - the redirect. You only show the results of the second requests and `$_POST` will be empty there.

To see the actual output of your POST request, you need to change the `success` function:

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);  
    // window.location.href = "reportr.php";   
}
```

Now you will see the output of `reportr.php` in the browser's developer tools console.

Comment: what if i want to go to get  redirected to reportr.php to see my output ?? is there any way ??

Comment: @AkshayWani That kind of defeats the purpose of using ajax. You could of course redirect to another page where data is simply pulled from the database, based on an ID or something similar that you pass to that page.